# How to list all registered applications in identity server for a user?

Tags: identityserver4, identityserver3

I am using IdentityServer3 for authentication. The indetityserver has 3 applications configured.
https://www.app1.com
https://www.app2.com
https://www.app3.com

A user is registered for all 3 applications. Currently user has to goto respective application url (for eaxample https://www.app1.com), which redirects user to identityserver for authentication and upon authentication user get redirected back to app web site.

Is there way to configure IdentityServer where user directly goes to identyserver, get authenticated and then identityserver list all the applications that user has access to? Here user would choose application he wants to login into.

Answer (score 0):

Give your users a link to the IdentityServer login page. After login, display a form (with tiles or links or something) where the user can choose the application.

Make sure that the link to the application sends the user to a secured page (or a method where you challenge the user). This would cause the application to redirect the user to IdentityServer, which notices that the user is already identified (cookie), returns to the application where the user is automatically logged in.

In case the user wants to quit the application, redirect back to the tiles page to choose another application.

Please note that a user is not specifically bound to one application. Once logged in, the user can access all applications. If you want to allow specific access, you may want to solve this with claims.

P.S. I didn't notice you are using IdentityServer3 as you also tagged this as IdentityServer4. But I would expect this would work the same for both versions.

Comment: where would the form ( with tiles or links) would go? do i need to create  another application that will have this form or the form is part of the identityserver application?

Comment: The user didn't choose yet. Assuming that the applications are registered as client, it could be part of IdentityServer since it knows both users and clients. Use it as a central landing page. Also think of the situation where application specific claims are issued. Should a user hit some part that is forbidden (missing claim) then the user is redirected to a /account/denied path. You could combine this with this form.

Comment: Maybe put a custom claim on the user, called something like "registeredApps" (clients).  Then you'd need a controller that looked at the user's claims and created the viewmodel of apps to display, then make a view using that.